# pandas from_json method usage

Tags: json, pandas

I have a JSON file like below,

```
{ 
“A”:1,
“B”:2,
“C”: [
      {“x”:1,“y”:2,“z”:3},
      {"x":2,"y":7,"z":77}
     ]
}
```

`pandas.from_json` returns me data frame with column A,B and C. But, actually I am looking for columns with x,y and z. Is there a way to get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html):

```
json = { 
"A":1,
"B":2,
"C": [{"x":1,"y":2,"z":3 },
      {"x":2,"y":7,"z":77}]
}


from pandas.io.json import json_normalize    
df = json_normalize(json, 'C')

print (df)

   x  y   z
0  1  2   3
1  2  7  77
```

If need all columns:

```
df = json_normalize(json, 'C', ['A','B'])

print (df)
   x  y   z  B  A
0  1  2   3  2  1
1  2  7  77  2  1
```